# C# Razor Replace function

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

My `<title>VARIABLE</title>` include text "| website" in all my titles , I want to remove this text from my title using replace function.  I have no experience of C# but need to do this work. I have checked its RAZOR framework. Please add the code between the title tag using my variable you can see in the title tag of code.

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
@using Sana.RazorDeface
@{ 
    var customerServiceUrl = Url.Sana.Resolve(Shop.Settings.CustomerServicePage);

}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if IE 8]><html class="no-js ie8"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]><html class="no-js ie9"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 10]><html class="no-js ie10"><![endif]-->
<html class="no-js" lang="@Sana.PageLanguage">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <title>@PageInfo.Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="description" content="@Html.FormatMetaDescription(PageInfo.MetaDescription)" />
    <meta name="robots" content="@PageInfo.Robots" />
    <meta name="generator" content="Sana Commerce" />
    @When(PageInfo.Robots.Index, render => Html.CanonicalLink())
    @When(PageInfo.Robots.Index, render => Html.AlternateLinks())
    @Html.Partial("_PageTracking")
    @Styles.Render("~/content/css/store")
    <link href="@Url.ThemeStyleSheet(PageInfo.UseDefaultTheme.GetValueOrDefault(true))" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    @Html.Partial("_ExternalFonts")
    @When(Sana.IsPrintMode, then => Styles.Render("~/content/css/extra/print"))
    @When(Sana.IsEditorMode, then => Styles.Render("~/content/css/extra/editor"))
    @When(Sana.IsProfilerEnabled, then => Styles.Render("~/content/css/extra/profiler"))
    @RenderSection("Head", required: false)
    @Html.EnterpriseDebugString()
    @Sana.HtmlInjection("Head")
<meta name="google-site-verification" content="nbS3GoTrL6EPv9TF7RbIDwT9hpvbEb6ecPZfSsxWSzs" />
<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-135059944-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-135059944-1');
</script>
</head>
<body class="@GetPageCssClasses()" data-url-root="@Href("~/")" data-url-home="@When(Shop.CommerceContext.NoSqlConnection, Href("~/"), Url.Sana.HomePage())" data-currency="@Shop.CommerceContext.CurrencyId">
    @Html.Partial("_PageTrackingNoscript")
    @Sana.HtmlInjection("BodyStart")
    <div class="site">
        <noscript>
            <div class="msg-block no-script">
                @Sana.RichText("NoScriptMessage")
            </div>
        </noscript>
        @(Sana.IsProfilerEnabled ? Html.Partial("_Profiler") : null)
        @When(Sana.IsEditorMode, render => Html.Partial("_FrontendEditorToolbar"))
        <header class="nav-is-closed">
            <div class="header-blocks-wrapper">
                <div class="top-header">
                    @Html.Partial("_HeaderInfoMessage")
                    <div class="top-action">
                        @RenderSection("Language", required: false)
                        @if (!customerServiceUrl.IsEmptyString())
                    {
                        <a href="@customerServiceUrl" class="top-hyp font-smaller">@Sana.SimpleText("CustomerService")</a>
                }
                        @RenderSection("Login", required: false)
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="middle-header">
                    @RenderSection("Logo", required: false)
                    @RenderSection("Search", required: false)
                    @RenderSection("Basket", required: false)
                </div>

                <div class="bottom-header">
                    <div class="center">
                        <div class="nav-opener-wrapper">
                            <div class="nav-opener"></div>
                        </div>
                        @RenderSection("TopMenu", required: false)
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </header>
        <div class="school-selection-header">

                                @RenderSection("TopSchoolSelection", required: false)

        </div>
        <div class="content">
            @RenderBody()
        </div>
        <footer>
            <div class="center">
                <div class="columns-general top">
                    @RenderSection("Sitemap", required: false)
                    @RenderSection("Newsletter", required: false)
                </div>
                <div class="columns-general bottom">
                    @RenderSection("Footer", required: false)
                </div>
            </div>
        </footer>
        @Html.Partial("LoadingIndicator")
    </div>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Scripts.RenderFormat("<script defer src=\"{0}\"></script>", "~/content/script/libs")
    @Scripts.RenderFormat("<script defer src=\"{0}\"></script>", "~/content/script/shop")
    @if (Sana.IsProfilerEnabled)
    {
        @Html.ProfilerIncludes()
        @Scripts.RenderFormat("<script defer src=\"{0}\"></script>", "~/content/script/profiler")
    }
    @When(Sana.IsEditorMode, render => Html.Partial("_FrontendEditorScripts"))

    @RenderSection("Scripts", false)
    @DefaceScripts.Profiler(Context)
    @Sana.HtmlInjection("BodyEnd")
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `Need help ASAP`  Please read:  [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Hope this works.

```
 <title>@PageInfo.Title.Replace("| website"," ")</title>
```